# jqwidgets treegrid setcellvalue function not working on editor on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, treegrid, jqwidget

I am using the [jqwidgets tree grid](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtreegrid/index.htm)

I am trying to implement onchange listener for the cell editor based on the following requirements

- On Change of a cell value in particular row it should make changes in other cell in that particular row.

What I have tried so far for this is :

In the init editor function I have added following code for onchange listener

```
initEditor: function (row, cellvalue, editor, celltext, width, height) {

                      editor.bind('change',function onCHangeOf(value) {
                     curValue = this.value;

                    $("#treeGrid").jqxTreeGrid('setCellValue', row, 'Total', curValue);
                     });

                   }
```

But the above code is not working when I am trying to `setCellValue` for the cell **Total**

I have created the following JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3zGhL/8/

I have also used other event listener for the same implementation like onBlur,onCellValuechanged but the problem still exists that is where i think the problem is with the `setCellValue` function i am using here

Can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setCellValue sets the value of a Cell and it does it correctly even in your sample, but note that it would not update automatically the value of an already opened Cell Editor, because by default your implementation overrides a default logic. If you want to set the value of an editor, use the initEditor of your "Title" column.

Comment: Yes you are right,changing the edit mode to single cell edit helped me to make it work for calculations.